# copy of a slice from a DataFrame warning, loc method not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, isnull

There are many posts on this topic but unfortunately the solution provided (using loc) is not working for me. In my dataset, I have feature 'GarageYrBlt' which is the year in which the garage was built; and another feature 'YearBuilt' which is the year in which the house was built. The GarageYrBlt has some null values.

since GarageYrBlt and YearBuilt are strongly correlated, I am trying to replace the null values of GarageYrBlt by corresponding values of YearBuilt.

```
df.GarageYrBlt[df.GarageYrBlt.isnull()] = df.YearBuilt[df.GarageYrBlt.isnull()]
```

This gave the warning "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"
So I tried the .loc method as shown below, but no change. I still get the same error. Any suggestions?

```
df.loc[:,"GarageYrBlt"][df.GarageYrBlt.isnull()] = df.loc[:,"YearBuilt"][df.GarageYrBlt.isnull()].copy()
```

Comment: looks like I was using loc wrong, this seems to work: data.loc[data.GarageYrBlt.isnull(),"GarageYrBlt"] = data.loc[data.GarageYrBlt.isnull(),"YearBuilt"]

Comment: Your usage in the comment here is correct, which is `df.loc[row_index, column_idx]`. When you used `df.loc[...][...]` in your original question, the second set of `[]` is probably what caused the warning about copying a slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in a single slice operation.  So instead of this:

```
df.loc[:,"GarageYrBlt"][df.GarageYrBlt.isnull()] = df.loc[:,"YearBuilt"][df.GarageYrBlt.isnull()].copy()
```

Do this:

```
df.loc[df.GarageYrBlt.isnull(), "GarageYrBlt"] = df.loc[df.GarageYrBlt.isnull(), "YearBuilt"]
```

Or easier:

```
df.GarageYrBlt.fillna(df.YearBuilt, inplace=True)
```